# Get parent theme version

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style, parent-theme, wp-get-theme

How do I get the parent theme's version in a child theme?

I want to use it when loading the parent theme's stylesheet.

Here's how I load the stylesheets in the child theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function sometheme_enqueue_styles() {

  // Get parent theme version
  $parent_theme_version = wp_get_theme()->parent()->get( 'Version' );

  // Load parent theme stylesheet
  wp_enqueue_style( 'sometheme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), $parent_theme_version );

  // Load child theme stylesheet
  wp_enqueue_style( 'sometheme-child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( 'sometheme-style' ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
  );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sometheme_enqueue_styles', 11 );
```

However, this will use the child theme's version for both stylesheets...

I have also tried this:

```
$parent_theme = wp_get_theme('sometheme');
$parent_theme_version = $parent_theme->get( 'Version' );
```

...and this:

```
$parent_theme = wp_get_theme(get_template());
$parent_theme_version = $parent_theme->get( 'Version' );
```

But again, the parent theme version keeps getting the version from the child theme.

#### Solution

It turns out that both `wp_get_theme()->parent()->get( 'Version' );` and `wp_get_theme()->parent()->Version;` works.

The problem was that the parent theme was using `$theme_version = wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' );` as well, which means that it will use the child themes version.

Since I own the parent theme, I changed the parent theme to `wp_get_theme('sometheme')->get( 'Version' );` so that it always uses its own version.

That way, I can use either `wp_get_theme()->parent()->get( 'Version' );` or `wp_get_theme()->parent()->Version;` in the child theme.

Comment: Are you validating that your `$parent_theme` assignment is actually getting the parent?  See below for one option to test this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [WP_Theme class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_theme/), the `get` method gives you a sanitized theme header. You cannot use it to extract a property. Actually you don't need to, as you can access it directly like this:

```
 // get the parent object
 $parent = wp_get_theme()->parent();
 // get parent version
 if (!empty($parent)) $parent_version = $parent->Version;
```

Comment: This should work as expected.  Local testing confirms for me.  I suspect the OP might be having a separate issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

As @jdm2112 pointed out, I had a separate issue. The fact is that both `wp_get_theme()->parent()->get( 'Version' );` and `wp_get_theme()->parent()->Version;` works. 

The problem was that the parent theme was using `$theme_version = wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' );` as well, which means that it will use the child themes version. 

Since I own the parent theme, I changed the parent theme to `wp_get_theme('sometheme')->get( 'Version' );` so that it always uses its own version. Not sure if that's the best way to do it...?

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your edit based on the suggested method from cjbj, make sure you are using the actual directory name for the parent theme when calling `wp_get_theme()`.  Note - this is not the slug or written name of the theme in many cases.

If `sometheme` is the file directory for the parent theme, then this should return the parent theme object:

```
var_dump( wp_get_theme( 'sometheme' ) );
```

Within that theme object is the version.  Let's make sure you are getting the parent theme returned first.

Add your output for that `var_dump()` statement to your question if it is not the parent theme.